# Sqldataapter advice

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

At present i have a the following code populating a datagridview showing the user account information on our system. What i want to do do is have a checkbox on the datagridview for the option "accountenabled" and a update button at the bottom of the form so it will update all users that have had changes made against them. I am currently pulling the data back using an sqldatareader however from what i have read i need to use a sqldataadapter. I`ve created the column names on the datagridview and the reader is currently pulling everything back correctly.

Could someone please point me in the right direction of doing this with an sqldatadapter?

Thanks

```
public UserAdmin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Load user list

        // Locals
        Functionality func = new Functionality();
        SqlConnection supportDB = null;
        SqlCommand CheckUser = null;
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string User = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
        string spName = "gssp_ShowAllUsers";

        try
        {
            using (supportDB = new SqlConnection(GSCoreFunc.ConnectionDetails.getConnectionString(ConnectionType.SupportDB)))
            {
                using (CheckUser = new SqlCommand(spName, supportDB))
                {
                    // Set the command type
                    CheckUser.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Populate the parameters.
                    CheckUser.Parameters.Add(func.CreateParameter("@spErrorID", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Output, DBNull.Value));

                    // Open the connection and populate the reader with the SP output
                    supportDB.Open();
                    rdr = CheckUser.ExecuteReader();
                    if (CheckUser.Parameters["@spErrorID"].Value != null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }

                    // If the data reader has rows display output on label
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        //Output values
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            //Bind to data table
                            dgvUsers.Rows.Add(rdr["agentID"].ToString(), rdr["createdon"].ToString(), rdr["firstname"].ToString(), rdr["lastname"].ToString(), rdr["username"].ToString(), rdr["emailaddress"].ToString(), rdr["Departments"].ToString(), rdr["accountenabled"].ToString(), rdr["AgentAccountLevel"].ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    // Close reader and connection.
                    rdr.Close();
                    supportDB.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Show error message
            string error = ex.ToString(); //Real error
            string FriendlyError = "There has been error loading the user list"; // Error user will see
            GSCoreFunc.ShowMessageBox.msgBoxErrorShow(FriendlyError);

            //Log error to ExceptionDB
            GSCoreFunc.ReportException.reportEx(GSCoreFunc.ApplicationInformation.ApplicationName, error, FriendlyError, GSCoreFunc.ApplicationInformation.ComputerName, GSCoreFunc.ApplicationInformation.OperatingSystem, GSCoreFunc.ApplicationInformation.screenSize, GSCoreFunc.ApplicationInformation.IPAdddress, GSCoreFunc.ApplicationInformation.domainName);// Pass error to GSCoreFunc to log to the ExceptionDB
        }
    }

    private void btClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Close window
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the SqlDataReader. The SqlDataAdapter is a higher level api that allows you to iterate through an SqlDataReader and store a copy of the results in a DataTable or a DataSet. This copy can then be used as the data source for your DataGridView.

One thing I would change with your code would be to use data binding instead of generating each row manually. If you set the DataSource property of the grid to either your SqlDataReader or to a DataTable filled by an SqlDataAdapter and then call the grids DataBind() method the grid should be filled automatically with your data.

To control the columns you would make sure your query only returns the required columns, and you would define the column setup in your aspx-file.

Using data binding is generally an easier and more flexible approach, so you should consider using that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rune. Its a winform im working on. Could you provide an example of how i would go about using data binding insteading of generating each row?

Comment: @Steve: Look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860 The first interesting example is the one for Data-Bound list controls. It is simple, but covers the basics. Further down you have an example of how to bind to a DataReader instead of a data table.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this code](http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-datagridview-sqlserver.htm)

Initialize a sql adapter and fill with data source . Use a connection string other than using sql data source because it would be easy for customizing. :)